# Is it possible to use real SSL certificates (Nginx/Apache) on localhost?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to build localhost copy of working application to improve development process.

I am using docker-compose for that.
Now I am getting an error during sending request from one container to another. I know that it is related to SSL check. I am using self signed certs for docker compose.

I dont want to change the code to disable SSL valid check. Is is possible to use real existing cert from web server on localhost? Or something like that?

Comment: Is adding your self-signed certificate to the Java trust store not an option?

Comment: @AnthumChris - no :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass your local certs folder to the Nginx container?

```
# docker-compose.yaml

services:
  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./my-certs:/etc/nginx/certs
```

```
# nginx.conf

server {
  ...
  ssl_certificate     certs/public.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key certs/private.key;
}
```